# Why doesn't IN transition work for the first opened Form?

Tags: java-me, lwuit, midp, lwuit-form

In the `startApp()` of the MIDLet I show a Form ( the main Form of the application ) . The problem is that even if I set `setTransitionInAnimator` then the Transition is not effect at runtime ! So how to make transition for the first opened Form from the MIDLet ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transitions apply between 2 components/forms hence the first form will never have a transition since there is nothing to transition from. E.g. a splash screen will never slide into place it will just appear.

To effect a transition just create a blank form and apply to it a transition out, I would suggest avoiding that strategy though since no device performs such a transition. Devices such as iPhone/Android who perform a transition to show the initial form do that in the native layer which applies to LWUIT applications as well.